# Using Union all to SQL Queries to create Dynamic Column Names

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

Please se my code below

```
set @query = 'SELECT tenantcode, locationd, name, MONTH,' +
'Year1 as' + '[' + @Year1  + ']'  +
',Year2 as' + '[' + @Year2  + ']'  + 
',Year3 as' + '[' + @Year3  + ']'  +
',Year4 as' + '[' + @Year4  + ']'  +
',Year5 as' + '[' + @Year5 + ']'  +
'from #SalesPerYear' +
'UNION ALL' +
'SELECT  tenantcode, locationd, name, total , t1, t2,t3,t4,t5 FROM #TotalSales ' 


EXECUTE (@query)
```

That is part of my codes in the desire in achieving a final output in SQL WHERE COLUMN NAMES should be dynamic (in this case, the changing YEAR NAME such as 2011, 2012,2013 etc)

When execute my stored procedure, there is an error like this

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near 'tenantcode'.
```

When I remove the Union all, both queries worked individually. What could be the problem here.

Comment: run this command "print @query", and post here what it is returning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a space between `from #SalesPerYear` and `UNION ALL` and also the following `SELECT`.

```
....
'from #SalesPerYear '
                   ^---here
'UNION ALL' +
' SELECT  tenantcode, locationd, name, total , t1, t2,t3,t4,t5 FROM #TotalSales ' 
 ^--- and here
```

Thats the easiest way to demonstrate it, you can of course just put a space either side of `UNION ALL`

```
' UNION ALL ' +
```

Comment: wow! it actually worked! though I find it really weird that how a space can ruin the whole codes. thanks

Comment: Really? Do you think `SELECT x,y,z from myTableUNIONselect a,b,c from myothertable` looks like valid SQL if you were to type it into SQL management studio?

Comment: YAH! ok you got me there! I thought I had a space on the code before UNION and SELECT.